# one way Fisher's Exact Test

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, statistical-significance, fishers-exact-test

I can use a chi square test for a one way table like this:

```
frequencies <- c(12, 3, 9, 19, 3, 14, 13)
chisq <- chisq.test(frequencies)
chisq
```

However, when I do something similar for the Fisher's Exact Test like this:

```
fisher.test(frequencies)
```

It results in:

```
Error in stats::fisher.test(x, y, ...): 'x' must have at least 2 rows and columns
Traceback:
```

I am a bit confused. Can one not do a one way Fisher's Exact Test? Thanks.

Comment: The short answer is no.  See any account of the test, such as at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_exact_test.  Consider asking a more constructive question, such as telling us why you might be looking for alternatives to the chi square test and what properties a good alternative should have.

Comment: @whuber - sorry the expected values are lower than 5 for some entries using the actual data. My reading suggests that one should use the Fisher's Exact Test instead of chi square in such situations.

Comment: All the expected values in the example you posted equal 13.3, which far exceeds 5.

Comment: @whuber - this was a made-up example but yes you are right. I changed the data.

Comment: According to [Zar, 2010](https://www.pearson.com/us/higher-education/program/Zar-Biostatistical-Analysis-5th-Edition/PGM263783.html) : "it is acceptable to have expected frequencies as small as 1.0 for testing at $\alpha$ as small as 0.05, or as small as 2.0 for $\alpha$ as small as 0.01." But if you still want to apply a multinomial test to your data, you can still use the function `rstatix::multinom_test`!

Comment: Because your new expected frequencies all still exceed 5 for a uniform distribution (which is the implicit default in this case), I wonder whether you are forgetting to tell us something about how you obtain those expectations: what exactly is your null hypothesis?

Comment: @whuber it is related to this: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/495056/outage-frequency-analysis - here I want to look at the data one dimensionally - to see if, for example, some days have significantly more outages ...

Answer (score 1):

#### For fixed total number of observations

If the total number of observations is fixed, then the sample distribution of the observations, given the null hypothesis, will be a multinomial distribution and an exact test can be the ["multinomial test"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_test).

You can compute this exactly, approximate it by using a Monte Carlo approach, Pearson's chi-squared test, or with a likelihood ratio (this latter one relates to a [G-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-test)).

In R the package `XNomial` can do all of them

```r
library(XNomial)

obs <- c(12, 3, 9, 19, 3, 14, 13)
n <- sum(obs)
k <- length(obs)
p <- 1/k
predicted <- rep(n*p,k)
xm <- xmulti(obs,predicted)
```

Giving

$$\begin{array}{lcl}
p_{\chi^2} &=& 0.002994365 \\
p_{\text{Likelihood ratio}} &=& 0.001218835 \\
p_{\text{exact}} &=& 0.001233232
\end{array}$$

This package uses some corrections for the statistics or the p-values. If you would compute the values manually then you get the same statistics but slightly different p-values.

```r
obs <- c(12, 3, 9, 19, 3, 14, 13)
n <- sum(obs)
k <- length(obs)
p <- 1/k
predicted <- rep(n*p,k)

numerator <- factorial(n) * p^n
logdenominator <- sum(lfactorial(obs))
p_obs <- numerator/exp(logdenominator)

### MonteCarlo
set.seed(1)
nmc = 10^6
counts = 0
for (i in 1:nmc) {
  x <- rmultinom(1, n, rep(p,k))
  sample <- sum(lfactorial(x))
  if (sample >= logdenominator) {counts = counts+1}
}
counts/nmc

### Pearson's Chi-squared
chi2 <- sum((obs-predicted)^2/predicted)
1-pchisq(chi2,k-1)

### Log Likelihood ratio
f_obs <- obs/n
LLR <- sum(obs*log(predicted/obs))
test_ratio <- -2*log(p_theory/p_obs)
1-pchisq(ratio,k-1)
```

Comment: Thanks - could you please tell me what you mean by "total number of observations is fixed"?

Comment: With your observations 12, 3, 9, 19, 3, 14, 13 the total number is 73. If you performed your experiment such that this 73 was fixed then you have the multinomial distribution. An alternative situation might be that your sampling allows different total number. In that case it might be for instance that those counts are Poisson distributed.