# outage frequency analysis

Tags: r, mathematical-statistics, statistical-significance, chi-squared-test, fishers-exact-test

I have several outage data points. Each outage has a time category (TP1 - TP3 - one could argue this is an ordinal variable) and week day.

The rolled up (artificial) frequencies data looks as follows:

```
set.seed(42)
v1 <- runif(n = 7, min = 6, max = 30)
v2 <- runif(n = 7, min = 50, max = 55)
v3 <- runif(n = 7, min = 6, max = 30)
v <- round(c(v1, v2, v3), 0)

frequencies <- matrix(v, nrow=3, ncol=7)

rownames(frequencies) <- c("TP1", "TP2", "TP3")
colnames(frequencies) <- c("mon", "tue", "wed", "thu", "fri", "sat", "sun")
frequencies[3, 2] <- 10000
frequencies
```

[image]

I made Tue in time period TP3 extra large. Which statistical test(s) could I use to say there is an issue (i.e. the outages are not uniformly distributed). I think the chi square is appropriate or possibly the Fisher's exact test (the actual data has zeros in some cells or values less than 5).

Is it also possible to pin down the issue (e.g. TP3 on a Tuesday produces significantly more outages).

Perhaps one could also fit a Poisson distribution (somehow) and test each cell's value. If the value diverges very much from what is expected the entry may be deemed an outlier.

I hope this makes sense?

Comment: Could you explain what an "outage data point" is and what your "frequencies" refer to?  They're obviously not counts, nor does your software reveal anything about the actual data you have.

Comment: @whuber - sorry my artificial reproducible data generator code did not produce integers. I corrected this now. The entry in row 3 column 2 of 10000 means that there were 10000 outages on a Tuesday in time period 3 (TP3). This should now be clear hopefully?

Comment: I think this fits naturally in a (Poisson) regression framework where you are free to specify additive and interaction terms for tp and day of week. Then you just need to deal with multiple testing issues

Comment: @seanv507 thanks. just to get this clear. fit a poisson regression model like so (just using main effects) number_of_outages ~ day_of_week + time_period. If the actual is (significantly?) larger than the prediction we have an outlier/anomaly?

Comment: Yes, but then you would do significance test on coefficient. ( And suspect you want interaction)

Comment: @seanv507 ok might as well do number_of_outages ~ day_of_week + time_period + day_of_week * time_period (never sure if to center and include intercept?)

Comment: NB in r it will default to intercept. * Also generates linear terms. Centring is useful for interpretability

Comment: @seanv507 thanks I know. From top of my head, I think the equation would be number_of_outages ~ 1 -day_of_week + time_period + day_of_week * time_period